# Can I use a maneuver to meet the prerequisites for a martial stance, then swap out that maneuver later?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat-maneuver, tome-of-battle, feat-qualifications, retraining

I'm a Warblade in the process of reaching level 6. I have one level 1 Diamond Mind maneuver. Is the following possible:

For my level six feat, I want to take Martial Stance to attain the Diamond Mind stance Pearl of Black Doubt. It needs one Diamond Mind maneuver as a pre-req.

Can I take that feat and add that maneuver, the swap out that maneuver for one of a different school as per the Warblade leveling rules?

Answer (score 8):

## Advancing a level has an order of operations

This order is detailed in the *Player's Handbook* (58-9), but it's absent from the SRD so that Wizards of the Coast can sell you books. What you need to know from it is this: *class* decisions are made before *feat* decisions.

Thus, this warblade must use his ability to learn a new maneuver in place of an old maneuver *before* picking as his level 6 feat Martial Stance, and, were the warblade to've ditched that lone Diamond Mind maneuver, the warblade can no longer meet the Martial Stance feat's prerequisite for taking the stance pearl of black doubt.

However, once the warblade *knows* the stance pearl of black doubt *via* the feat Martial Stance, because "[s]tances are considered maneuvers for the purpose of fulfilling prerequisites for learning higher-level maneuvers, or qualifying for prestige classes or feats" (*Tome of Battle* 43), the warblade can safely swap out (perhaps at level 8?) that *other* Diamond Mind maneuver that he used to meet the Martial Stance feat's prerequisite and continue to meet the prerequisite for the feat Martial Stance *and* the stance pearl of black doubt *with the stance itself*. (Note that this—that is, meeting a feat's prerequisite with what's, essentially, the feat's benefit—*does* make this DM a little queasy, but it's not like the warblade's casting spells or anything, so whatever.)

Comment: I am actually tempted to downvote this answer since it gives absolutely no mention of the fact that *almost no one does, and absolutely no one ever should, get this pedantic.* This is accurate to the rules, but it’s arguably not *useful* without that.

Comment: I'm guessing it can't count as its own pre-requisite?

Comment: @KRyan The question essentially asks *Can I take a feat, trade out the feat's prerequisite, and then let the feat's benefit meet its own prerequisite?* I mean, yeah, the non-pedant way of answering that is *No, and knock it off!* but I figured a rules-based answer might be better. `:-)` (I really hope that's not, instead, a comment on tone; the answer's not intended to be condescending!)

Comment: Actual character. I meant more so for having it count towards maintaining itself. If I needed one as a pre-req to take it that makes sense that it can't be used for ts elf, but once I have it I technically have one Diamond Mind maneuver. None of this matters however since class things happen before feats.

Comment: The stance itself meets Martial Stance’s prerequisite. If you know *wolf fang strike* and take Martial Stance to gain *hunter’s sense*, you know two Tiger Claw maneuvers. If you then swap *wolf fang strike* at 4th level for *mountain hammer*, you know one Tiger Claw maneuver—​ *hunter’s sense* ​—and thus continue to meet the prerequisite for Martial Stance. The only concern here is about doing it all in one level, which gets into absurdly-pedantic territory vis a vis level-up order of operations.

Comment: @KRyan While I find that icky, that sounds legal: The stance (which counts as a maneuver) *is* already on the adept's character sheet. The adept met the prerequisites when he took the feat and continues to meet them even after ditching the prerequisite that got him the feat. I'll adjust my answer momentarily. (Also, what's so darn *pedantic* about following the level-up rules?)

Comment: It’s a lot less icky than having a feat that does nothing. The swapping of maneuvers is an intended (and *good*, design-wise) part of the initiating system.

Comment: @KRyan I think we can agree that it works but still disagree as to whether it's a bug or a feature. `:-)`

Comment: Per the recent related question, rereading the rules carefully, they explicitly state that prerequisites are only for “learning,” “selecting,” or “choosing” a maneuver. Not only does it appear to be an intentional feature that you can swap away stuff you had used as a prerequisite, “bootstrapping” as we were discussing here isn’t even necessary.